# How to get all latitudes and longitudes from source place to destination place

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

I want to get all the latitudes and longitudes from google map.

For Example : suppose i have enter lat and lon of source and destination and the path is drawn on the map as below:

[image]

so now i want all the lat and lon between this A source and B destination. and that all lat and lon have to store in the database.

so when i track my car and that car are not moving on this path/way then at that it will fire some action like send me email etc.

i am developing with asp.net c#.

so how can i get the all the lat and lon ?

i am using below script

```
  <script>
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.304634, 73.161070),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }),
       directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
       displayer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            draggable: true
        });

            displayer.setMap(map);
            directions.route({
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(22.304634, 73.161070),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(23.022242, 72.548844),
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result) {
                displayer.setDirections(result);
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        google.maps.event.addListener(displayer, 'directions_changed', some_method);
    </script>
```

Comment: have you consulted with the `Google Maps API` ?

Comment: yes i go through the API but i didnt find the solution .

Comment: what do you consider "all"? There are an infinite number of points between any two locations.

Comment: ya exactly. but it is good if i am getting "all" at 10 meter of interval

Comment: you're using DirectionService to draw the "path"?

Comment: yes i am using DirectionService.

Comment: what have you tried? Show some JavaScript.
Did you look at `overview_path` property of the `google.maps.DirectionsRoute` object?

Comment: @deepak check out my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop over the `overview_path` property of the `google.maps.DirectionsRoute` object. Then create your object (or just serialize `overview_path`) to send it to the server and stock it in the data base.

Chek out this example for how to loop over the `overview_path`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; min-height: 600px; min-width: 700px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map-canvas { height: 50%; }
      #panel { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 50%; margin-left: -180px; z-index: 5; background-color: #fff; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel">
      <label>Origin
          <input id="origin" type="text" value="">
      </label>
      <label>Destination
          <input id="destination" type="text" value="">
      </label>
      <input type="button" value="GetDirections" onclick="calcRoute()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="vertex-container">
        <label>Points</label>
        <ul id="vertex">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.85727000, 2.35238)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }

        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById('origin').value;
            var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
                        var routes = response.routes;
                        for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                            var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                            var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                                var li = document.createElement('li');
                                li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                                ul.appendChild(li);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function getLiText(point) {
            var lat = point.lat(),
                lng = point.lng();
            return "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good work. Thank you very much.. but can i ask one question..? this path is auto generated by google. but suppose i want to select other path then how its works? suppose i found 3 different path but i want to slect my own the path then how can i do that?

Comment: How would you find the 3 different paths? I'm not sure to understand your question

Comment: In this direction when we enter source and destination then it will create a path between those two places . but it takes the only 1 path. But When suppose there are 3 different paths between those two place then how can we select the other path ? Get this?

Comment: You do that with the `DirectionsRenderer`, if you have a more elaborate question with an example post another question ;)

Comment: if you are going to answer then i dont mind to post the other question :-)

Comment: and one more thing how can i store all these lat and lot to y database?

Comment: One question one post, it is the philosophy around here. But I told you in the answer above, yo serialize the object and you send it to server (c# code).

Comment: but i am not that level excellent developer. and i dont know how to add these via html code to c#.. ok will post here..

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619285/how-to-get-all-latitudes-and-longitudes-from-source-place-to-destination-place-f" check this link please