# How to get all latitudes and longitudes from source place to destination place from different routes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

currently i am able to fetch all the lat and lon from the source to destination place.

But with this i am only able to get 1 path .

`Now i want the option to select 1 route path from the different route path from source to destination place`.

and also i want to store these all lat and lon to my database.

```
Database structure :

Rid Lat Lon
```

i am using asp.net c# technology..

```
How can i get the option for select path and according to that path need to get all the lat and lon.
```

and also that all lat and lon need to store in my database with c# code.

how can i perform this task?

i am using belowe code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 600px;
            min-width: 700px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #map-canvas {
            height: 50%;
        }

        #panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -180px;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel">
        <label>
            Origin
          <input id="origin" type="text" value="">
        </label>
        <label>
            Destination
          <input id="destination" type="text" value="">
        </label>
        <input type="button" value="GetDirections" onclick="calcRoute()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="vertex-container">
        <label>Points</label>
        <ul id="vertex">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.5911, 86.1611)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }

        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById('origin').value;
            var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
                        var routes = response.routes;
                        for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                            var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                            var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                                var li = document.createElement('li');
                                li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                                ul.appendChild(li);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function getLiText(point) {
            var lat = point.lat(),
                lng = point.lng();
            return "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you read the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)?

Comment: but how can i add that lat and lon to database..?

Comment: I answered the first question, for the second question, have you considered to use jQuery?

Comment: Thank you. i have tried the ajax and had develop webmethod class of that file but it will give me null values.

Comment: Well, out of the answer below writes the logic that give you the object you want to send to server, I suggest you to be a plain object and not a `Google Maps` object. someting like this : `[{lat: 1.223, lng: 2.122312}, {lat: 1.545435, lng : 2.54354343}]. When you get that, post another question (you know, one questio one post ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `Google Maps` to send you several options you have to build your `google.maps.DirectionsRequest` object setting the `provideRouteAlternatives` property to `true`, something like this:

```
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives : true
};
```

Then the `google.maps.DirectionsResult`object return you `routes` which is an `Array.<DirectionsRoute>` with the several `DirectionsRoute` objects (normaly it contains only one object when `provideRouteAlternatives`is set to `false`).

So from the code your are using :

`var routes = response.routes;`

`routes` will have several elements to iterate over. There you have you several paths.

Now when you do this `directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)` google maps will only *paint* the route in the index `0` of the array `routes`. To get Google Maps to draw another path you have yo specify the `routeIndex` propertuy of the `google.maps.DirectionsRendererOptions` object which you pass to the `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` constructor.

something like that will *paint* all the paths (you will need several `DirectionsRenderer` objects) :

```
var routes = response.routes;
for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ map: map, directions: response, routeIndex: j });
    directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);
    var points = routes[j].overview_path;
    var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

If you want the `Polylines` to be of different color you can also set that in the `DirectionsRendererOptions` object.

The entire code will be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; min-height: 600px; min-width: 700px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map-canvas { height: 50%; }
      #panel { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 50%; margin-left: -180px; z-index: 5; background-color: #fff; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel">
      <label>Origin
          <input id="origin" type="text" value="">
      </label>
      <label>Destination
          <input id="destination" type="text" value="">
      </label>
      <input type="button" value="GetDirections" onclick="calcRoute()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="vertex-container">
        <label>Points</label>
        <ul id="vertex">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var directionsDisplays = [];
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.85727000, 2.35238)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById('origin').value;
            var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
                        var routes = response.routes;
                        for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ map: map, directions: response, routeIndex: j });
                            directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);
                            var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                            var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                                var li = document.createElement('li');
                                li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                                ul.appendChild(li);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function getLiText(point) {
            var lat = point.lat(),
                lng = point.lng();
            return "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here, i get all the path but how can i select any 1 path and only that path lat and lon?

Comment: Like this `var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ map: map, directions: response, routeIndex: j });` your select the path you want by passing reoutIndex. So if routes have 2 paths and you pass 1, you will select and paint the second path (route)

Comment: but i am not able select any path on the map

Comment: read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event) you need to _master_ all those in order to _select_ a polyline which is basically listen to click event and change color or do want you want to on the click event handler of the polyline...

Comment: ok Thanks.. Can you tell me how can i store these in database?